# How can I measure website page load times from different countries?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, performance, web-applications, cloud-hosting

Recently, I migrated one of my personal projects into cloud and hosted the app on UK based servers.

I reside in Turkey and I would like to see how long it takes for my pages to load for UK based users and those from other countries.

I tried to ping the web site but I am getting  time outs. I think it is because of the load balancer.

Are there any services around that will allow me to monitor my website's page load times around the world?

Answer (score 11):

There's a great tool at http://www.webpagetest.org/ which allows you to measure the loading speed of a site. You can choose from a list of locations to test from and there are a few in the UK.

Answer (score 7):

http://loads.in/

I haven't used the monitoring features, but it does have a great load time tool, which you can choose different browsers and countries to test from.

Comment: loads.in is [down](https://i.imgur.com/ikeFeYX.png), at least right now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list at http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-free-online-tools-test-website-loading-speeds-create-faster-webpages/ Brasklapp: I have not tried all.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics includes [load time monitoring](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/05/measure-page-load-time-with-site-speed.html) (which can be filtered by visitor's geographic location or browser) as part of its free service.